# HQL: retrieve only several fields from entity by query including JOIN

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have the following hibernate tables:

```
public class Customer {
    //some fields... include customerId field
    public Person person;
    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL },  fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", unique = false, nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public Person getPerson e () {
        return person;
    }

}

 public class Person {
    //some fields...

    private Set<History> histories;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=History.class,cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name="person_m2m_history",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="person_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="persone_history_id")})
    public Set<History> getHistories() {
        return this.histories;
    }       
}
```

And also History table which its design is not relevant.
The relation of Customer to history table is by person entity.
I want to retrieve with HQL (and not native) several fields of customer, based on its history, but got an error.
What did I do wrongly?

Here is my Query:

```
entityManager.createQuery("select c.customerId, ph.changedOn,
    ph.changedField, from Customer c 
    left join fetch c.person p 
    left join fetch p.histories ph 
    where ph.changedField = 'name'")
```

This is the error cause by CreateQuery:

> 'org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the
>   owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
>   [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy
>   properties,classAlias=e,role=myProject.Customer.person,tableName=Person,tableAlias=person1_,origin=customer
>   customer0_,columns={customer0_.person_id
>   ,className=myProejct.Person}}] [select c.customerId, ph.changedOn,
>   ph.changedField, from Customer c left join fetch c.person p left join
>   fetch p.histories ph where ph.changedField = 'name']'

Answer (score 0):

Check your query,It have an extra comma near **from** 
`, from`

```
entityManager.createQuery("select c.customerId, ph.changedOn,
    ph.changedField from Customer c 
    left join fetch c.person p 
    left join fetch p.histories ph 
    where ph.changedField = 'name'")
```

it might work.